# Google Cloud Storage .flac audio file upload unsuccessfully (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

i am using Google Cloud Storage and Speech API to translate a file audio from my node.js implementation and i have problems with the uploading of the FLAC encoded audio file into Google Cloud Storage. It seems that it can upload correctly only files shorter than approximately 15 - 20 seconds, for the others, the API not throw an error and save an empty file (8.16KB).

The part of the code involved is the following:

```js
...

var binary = new Buffer(audio, 'base64');
  // write buffer to file


  var Readable = require('stream').Readable

  var s = new Readable
  s.push(binary) // the string you want
  s.push(null) // indicates end-of-file basically - the end of the stream


  var convertedFLACfilePath = "" + crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex')+".flac";
  var FfmpegCommand = require('fluent-ffmpeg');


  var command = new FfmpegCommand().input(s)
    .audioCodec('flac').save(convertedFLACfilePath)
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log('Processing finished !');

      const gcloudAuth = {
        projectId: '-------',
        keyFilename: '--------'
      };

      const bucketName = '--------';
      const filename = convertedFLACfilePath;
      const gcsUri = 'gs://' + bucketName + '/' + filename;

      const encoding = 'FLAC';
      const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
      const languageCode = '----';

      var gcloud = require('google-cloud')();

      var storageClient = gcloud.storage(gcloudAuth);
      var bucket = storageClient.bucket(bucketName);

      bucket.upload(filename)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(filename + ' uploaded to ' + bucketName);

        var speechClient = gcloud.speech(gcloudAuth);
  
        const config = {
          encoding: encoding,
          sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
          languageCode: languageCode
        };
        const audio = {
          uri: gcsUri
          //content: fs.readFileSync(filename).toString('base64'),
        };
        
        ...
```

There is some kind of limit for this type of operations?
Thank you,
Alex.